# How to boolean cut without losing shader effect?

Tags: materials, modifiers, shaders

I followed [this video](https://youtu.be/CHxelgYdBaI) to make a plank with wood effect shader.

However, when cutting the plank [at the end](https://youtu.be/CHxelgYdBaI?t=343), I'm getting this result:

[image]

I'm losing the shader effect on the cut part. I may have missed something in the video but I can't see what.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @moonboots: and i thought you know everything....i am a bit disappointed that you need a blend file for that.... :D :D

Comment: oh ok, actually it will only happen if the plank object has the same material as the cut object, so he could just remove this material from the plank object, unless he needs it

Comment: you see, I know everything

Comment: For more information on how this behaves, see my comments under both answers ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this is "normal", the cutting edge will get the material of the cutter object. If you want the cutting edge to have the same material, just give both objects the same material.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked great! It seems the guy in the video did it another way, any idea how he did it ?

Comment: Hi Devon, i am sorry, i didn't watch the video. But if you provide a time stamp of the video, where he does it, i will check it.

Comment: It's [at the end](https://youtu.be/CHxelgYdBaI?t=343)

Comment: ok, of course i cannot prove it, but...since i am creating tutorials myself, i can tell you: do not believe everything you see. Do not believe that they "don't do anything" just because you don't see it. Normally every cut in a tutorial is a clear sign of: the tutorial maker messed it up and had to "repair" it. And sometimes they cut away an important step. So i am pretty sure he added the same material to it (or made something else to make it work): there are exceptions, of course some people cut videos to make them more interesting...but in 99% of cuts: they "repaired" it ;)

Comment: @Chris, thankfully we are part of the 1%   :p

Comment: @Chris +1 I agree the tutor cheated on this one, but maybe in a different way: if the modifier's _Solver_ is switched to "Fast" instead of "Exact" (as it shows in the video) after the cut to disguise the error, than it wouldn't be necessary to add the material to the cutting object. Of course it could have been he just added the material, I just wanted to share the information that it could work without doing that :) But the "Fast" method won't work when they share materials, see moonboots' answer and my comment there.

Comment: thanks for that info! I never realized that there is that (!) difference and i think that's a bit weird that it acts that way.

Answer (score 5):

Actually it happens because if your original object (plank) shares a common material with the boolean object, this material will appear on the cut part. If you remove this material from the original object, this won't happen.

Comment: +1 Yeah, that's quite interesting. As I commented under @Chris answer, the cut would actually show the wood texture if the modifier was set to _Solver_ > "Fast" instead of "Exact". But not if they share a material as you pointed out. The problem with your answer is, if the _Solver_ is set to "Exact" (which it is by default), just removing the material won't work - it will still show the different material. And removing is only an option if you don't need it there, otherwise you can only make a duplicate of it.

Comment: ok, I need to test that  ;)